# How do I repair a concrete driveway that has been damaged by salt?

Tags: repair, concrete, driveway, damage

When we moved into our house the driveway was pitted due to salt use. We would like to repair this, but we are looking to know what the best method would be. Can a new layer of concrete be added over the damage or does the entire driveway need to completely pulled up and relaid?

Comment: Can you add a picture, please?

Answer (score 2):

If it's just pits and general ugliness, you can try [some concrete resurfacer](http://www.quikrete.com/ProductLines/ConcreteResurfacer.asp).

Just make sure to wash and rinse the driveway well like the directions say.  After it cures you can coat it with a sealer, and try not to use too much salt in the future.